# React Error Boundary is not catching errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a custom `ErrorBoundary` React Component with the following code

```
class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    state = {
        hasError: false,
        errorMessage: null
    };

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        this.setState({hasError: true})
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        this.setState({hasError: true, errorMessage: info})
    }

    render() {
        const { hasError, errorMessage } = this.state;
        console.log(hasError)
        const { children } = this.props;
        if (hasError) {
            return (<div><p>{hasError}</p><p>{ errorMessage}</p></div>)
        }
        return children
    }
}

export default ErrorBoundary
```

And while testing I am using it like this.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <div>{callUnknownFunc()}</div>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

But my app is crashing with the follow error in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: callMe is not defined
at App (App.js:74)


<ScrollToTop>
        {isCheckAuth && <Switch>
            {BlankRoutes}
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={cn('new-design app', {['fixed-app']:sidebarOpen})}>
                    <ModalManager/>
                    <Header />
                    {Routes}
                    <Footer />
                    <ErrorBoundary>
                        <div>{callUnknownFunc()}<div>
                    </ErrorBoundary>
                    {sidebarOpen && <div className='sidebar-overlay'></div>}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        </Switch> }
    </ScrollToTop>
```

Comment: Could you show some of the code in App.js around line 74

Comment: since "callMe" is not in the code you posted, I'll assume it's in a different component, and because of that is not cought by the error boundary.

Comment: @Rajesh, post full code of App.js since `callMe` is not here. `ErrorBoundary` is not the one causing this issue.

Comment: added app.js to the question

Comment: i am sorry error was caused by func callUnknownFunction